# Text floats out of its div

Tags: css, html, text, css-float

I'm dealing with a text who goes out of its div. I've coded the frontpage. So, no matter how long the main content is, it should force the sub-content (the grey area and the footer) to move down.

You see how the dummy text is acting

URL http://nicejob.is/clients/pizzahollin/www/divproblem.htm

I've accomplish this before but somehow it's not working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an element that only contains floating elements, the container's height will be zero. To fix this you can add a clearing div (`<div style="clear:both"></div>`).

If you add a clearing div at the end of the #under-content section, it will automatically adjust the height of the section to it's contents.

The other issue you have is that you are using relative positioning on your .opentext div elements. When you set a 'top' property, it actually pushes the content down, causing it to overlap with your #lower-container. You're better off using the 'margin-top' property, which will expand the size the .opentext div to fit all the contents.

So in short:

- Add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` at the end of the #under-content `<section>`
- Change the 'top:82px' to 'margin-top:82px' on your .opentext div

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanx. This did the trick with the background problem. I´ve managed it to asign with the footer div so I was surprise if I´ve was supposed to fix it any further.

Answer (score 3):

You've set an explicit height on that div. For it to reshape itself to its content, you'll need to set height:auto. (or never set its height in the first place)

**EDIT:** As ANeve said, you'll need to remove the height on both `.article` and `.opentext`, as well you'll need to put a `clear:left` on `.lower-container` to push the footer down.

Comment: Namely `.article` and `.opentext`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use wordwrap: break-word; for the div and it will break the word to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `height` property of your `.article` and `.opentext` divs.  If you remove this property, the content should expand accordingly.

However, you will also need to adjust the positioning of your background image.  You should set the background image of `.footer` itself, rather than relying on one statically-sized background image for the entire page.

Comment: ok, I see how it solves the problem and also reveals a small problem with the background image - Gonna fix that and than I should work properly

Thanx a lot :)